# Is program compiled to main memory or program memory when compiling?

Tags: memory, compilation, architecture, cpu

Suppose there is a c++ code. It is compile to binary code during compiling. My question is where does my computer store binary code, in main memory (DRAM) of in program memory (inside CPU).
And I also want to know can the content of program memory be changed by computer user?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a memory designed to holds *X*, that's where you need to put *X* in.

If the CPU of your reference architecture fetches instructions from a dedicated program memory, that's where the instructions must be stored since the CPU will look for them only there.

It's worth saying that modern processors are [von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture), they have a unified program and data memory ([internally they are not, e.g the caches are split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture)) while 
microcontroller are often [Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture).

I'll gloss over the advantages of each one and just say that each combination of attributes exists: you can have a CPU where the program memory is RO and programmed in factory, where it is programmable through an external interface, where it cannot be read by the program itself, where it can and where it can be written by the program itself.